# Can an HFS+ formatted drive be shared with Windows

Tags: windows, osx-server, file-sharing, smb, disk-format

I have a Mac Mini that I'm using as a media server. I just put together an external RAID enclosure and I'd like to format it as HFS+, primarily so I can use it for Time Machine backups. 75% of everything I do is with OS X or iOS, but I do have a Windows machine, and the majority of my friends and family use Windows. I'm not real clear on how network sharing protocols work. I know in order to share a volume with Windows (without installing some additional softare on windows) I have to set it up as an SMB share rather than AFP.

Will I be able to format the drive as HFS+ and create an SMB share for my Windows machines? Does the drive format matter in this case?

(The only reason I'm not just *trying* it is because the external drive is already formatted with an exFat partition and already has a fair amount of data on it. In order to reformat to HFS+ I would have to first sync all that data somewhere else, reformat, then sync it back - a task I'd rather not undertake if I won't be able to get the results I need.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attached to an OS X Server you can use the RAID-volume formatted to HFS+ or ExFAT to create shares for Windows clients.

After enabling the share it is accessible via AFP and SMB by default:

Example screenshot OS X Server 3.2.2 Mavericks:

[image]

Example screenshot OS X Server 5.0.15 El Capitan HFS+:

[image]

Example screenshot OS X Server 5.0.15 El Capitan ExFAT:

[image]

Both shares are accessible as usual (Data:HFS+ formatted/data2: ExFAT formatted):

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. One question - if I leave the volume formatted as ExFAT, can I still allocate Time Machine space using OSX Server? I am of the understanding that Time Machine ''required'' and HFS(+) formatted volume.

Comment: @JordanBondo I have to test this. I'll report back. You can't use an ExFAT volume to backup your OS X server **locally**.

Comment: @JordanBondo I haven't been able to use an ExFAT volume as shared Time Machine backup location. You would have to add a r/w sparse bundle.dmg, mount & share this and use it as an additional share for networked Time Machine backups

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm doing that currently, but I've had TimeMachine flip out a couple different times when using a sparsebundle, so I'm trying to get away from that. I think I'll just reformat as HFS+ and create an SMB share for lame old Windows. I'll check all this out when I get home & accept your answer when I can confirm this all works for me. Thanks again!